How to avoid loopback in wintun?
I created a interface using wintun and imported all traffic into this interface through the default route (0.0.0.0/0->wintun IP). The problem now is that packets received by the tun interface are sent, but due to the default route, the packets return, causing a loopback. In Linux, I bound the socket to a real interface using SO_BINDTOVICE, and the packet will be sent directly. How can I avoid loopback in Windows？
I tried to use the bind() function to bind this SOCKET to the IP address of a real interface, but there was still a loopback.The annotated code was adapted by me based on a Rust program, but it didn't work either.WSAIoctl(s,SIO_ROUTING_INTERFACE_CHANGE) also doesn't work,My real goal is to bypass the kernel protocol stack and avoid being captured by the routing table.
bool bind_socket(SOCKET s) {
    // multicast bind. multicast binding only supports udp socket
    // if_index:real if index
    if (tun_pf.if_index <= 0) {
        return true;
    }

    /*int optval;
    int optlen = sizeof(optval);
    if (getsockopt(s, SOL_SOCKET, SO_TYPE, (char*)&optval, &optlen) != 
    0) {
        log_error("getsockopt failed: %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    int val1 = IP_MULTICAST_IF;
    if (optval == SOCK_DGRAM && setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, &val1, 
    (char*)&tun_pf.if_index, sizeof(tun_pf.if_index)) != 0) {
        log_error("setsockopt IP_MULTICAST_IF failed: %d", 
    WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }
    int val2 = IP_UNICAST_IF;
    if (setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, &val2, (char*)&tun_pf.if_index, 
    sizeof(tun_pf.if_index))) {
        log_error("setsockopt IP_UNICAST_IF failed: %d", 
    WSAGetLastError());
        return false;
    }*/
    
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    const char* interfaceIP = "192.168.10.212";  // real interface addr
    
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(0); 
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(interfaceIP);
    if (bind(s, (struct sockaddr*)&addr, sizeof(addr)) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        log_error("Bind failed.");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}


I think it's better. If you could include the ".h" file that you're getting the windows socket libraries from it might help. I don't do socket programming with windows. So maybe somebody can already answer it. Cheers.

you mean param SOCKET s ? It's just a fd.Every connection will generate one, What I want is to bind it to a real interface.Just to add, the real interface index has been assigned to tun_pf.if_index.

Ended.setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_UNICAST_IF, (char*)&tun_pf.if_index, sizeof(tun_pf.if_index)) is useful, if_index should be big-endian.
